# R. Problem removing "#NAME?" (from an excel import) in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, excel-import

I have a .csv import from excel that has formula hangups that I am trying to remove.
A simple version of the data is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  species = letters[1:5],
  param1 = c("Place", "creek", "river", "#VALUE!", "desert"),
  param2 = c(-23.8, 43.23, "#NAME?", 45, 0.23),
  param3 = c(2.4, 2, 5.7, 0.00003, -2.5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) # This is a simplified version of the excel .csv import

df[df == "#VALUE!"] <- ""     # Removes excel cells where the formula left "#VALUE!"
df[df == "#NAME\\?"] <- ""   # This does not work

ndf <- df  # This is an attempt to reassign the columns to numeric
ndf
class(ndf$param2)
class(ndf$param3)
```

The main problem is that the data column `Param2` with this left in it is assigned to `character` when it needs to be `numeric`, or the functions I have to run on it do not work.

I've tried many different things, however I always nothing seems to recognise the cell. How do I remove "#NAME?" across the df please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an exact match (and not a regex match) so you don't need to escape special variables (like `?`, `!`) differently. Try :

```
df[df == "#VALUE!"] <- ""  
df[df == "#NAME?"] <- NA
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df
#  species param1 param2   param3
#1       a  Place -23.80  2.40000
#2       b  creek  43.23  2.00000
#3       c  river     NA  5.70000
#4       d         45.00  0.00003
#5       e desert   0.23 -2.50000

str(df)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ species: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ param1 : chr  "Place" "creek" "river" "" ...
# $ param2 : num  -23.8 43.23 NA 45 0.23
# $ param3 : num  2.4 2 5.7 0.00003 -2.5
```

Comment: I see. An earlier attempt threw up errors regarding the `?`, so that is what led me down that path. 
If I recall correctly, the `NA` will be a problem later on too. Is there an elegant way to leave it blank?

Comment: In R, column can have only one type turning it to blank will change them to character and not numeric.

Comment: I have blank cells in the excel sheet parameters that are blank, and they show up as blank in the parameter column. For e.g. param3[2] might be blank, and param3 would still show  as class `numeric` so long as that column didn't start out with a string in it. I'm not sure I understand the difference in this case then.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You can use `class(df$param2)` to know class of any column. After you run the code from my answer you can check the class again and see if it changed as expected.

Comment: param3 could be imported (e.g. `df <- read.csv(data.csv`) as `param3 = c(2.4, , 5.7, 0.00003, -2.5),`, i.e. there may do data in a particular cell, though it doesn't record it as `NA`. When `read.csv` imports it assigns classes to the columns. The functions I will use later will not accept an `NA`, but will accept a blank. Hence my problem.

Comment: If you have `param3` as blank `param3 = c(2.4, '' , 5.7, 0.00003, -2.5)`, check `class(param3)` . Also keeping the value as empty `param3 = c(2.4, , 5.7, 0.00003, -2.5)` returns an error. I would suggest to focus on the function that you want to apply and find out why it doesn't accept `NA` or what could be changed in the function so that it works with `NA`.

Comment: It seems it is an odd case where `read.csv` is able to do things that I cannot recreate with a "simple" dataset using `c( )`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution with `sub` to replace the unwanted values in one go:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("\\d"), ~sub("#.*", "NA", .)))
  species param1 param2 param3
1       a  Place  -23.8    2.4
2       b  creek  43.23      2
3       c  river     NA    5.7
4       d     NA     45  3e-05
5       e desert   0.23   -2.5
```

This solution is helpful if you do not know in which columns the unwanted values occur:

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~any(str_detect(.,"#"))), ~sub("#.*", "NA", .)))
```

This third solution both replaces the unwanted values anywhere and converts the columns to their correct type (thanks to @Ronak for inspiration):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~any(str_detect(.,"#"))), ~sub("#.*", "NA", .)),
         across(everything(), ~type.convert(., as.is = TRUE)))
```